# Converting lines to polylines with PostGIS/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, polyline-creation

I have a PostGIS table containing linestrings.  Some of these are parts of larger logical constructs (tracks, roads or boundaries).  I have been going though the data using snapping tools to make sure that that coordinates match up properly.

I now want to change my "tracks" layer to have polyline features, one for each logical track so I can label them on the maps and export them to GPS as a single named entity, or convert them to a route.

I am pretty sure that the answer will involve ST_MakeLine but I cannot see how construct the query?

The line table has an attribute 'part_of'  which has the name of the logical entity and a sequence attribute too.

Pointers to a good basic tutorial on working with various geometric constructs would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_UNION is what you are looking for: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html

However, if you've already cleaned up your data, it may be faster to use ST_COLLECT:  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Both will achieve what you are trying to do - create multilinestrings from linestrings

ST_UNION will produce a cleaner/more OGC compliant dataset as it will dissolve boundaries and re-order geometries to ensure there are no self-intersections.

Here is the documentation for ST_MULTI, which will return the geometry as a multigeometry:  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html

Comment: Thanks, these certainly look like they will do the job but what I can't figure out is how to actually use them in practice.  The examples in the manuals don't make any sense to me.  What I need is an example bit of SQL that  builds  polyline objects from a table of simple lines which have an attribute of belongs_to which defines aggregation.   Should I ask another question with a lot more details?

Comment: I think I am there.   This layer definition seems to do what I need: dbname='tiri_work' host=localhost port=5432 sslmode=disable key='part_of' table="(SELECT part_of, ST_Multi(ST_Collect(f.the_geom)) as multigeom FROM (SELECT  part_of, (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom
 As the_geom FROM base.line_master ) 
As f where  part_of != '' GROUP BY  part_of 
)" (multigeom) sql=   I need to do more testing and data cleanup put it appears to be doing the 'right thing'